# Launching URL using Selenium gecko driver

Tags: selenium

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class CheckoutFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method s
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
    }
}
```

While launching the URL - from Java code below error is coming
`"Server not Found`"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine. This might be the issue with Firefox version,
firefox version(I'm using) 52.0.1.

If still it is not working then try to switch to **chrome** instead of firefox.

Chrome Code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class CheckoutFlow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```